# Storing string larger than 65KB

Tags: magento2, product, image

I have a web call to an ERP system that contains a product's information including its image. All the information that I got from the web call is then stored to its corresponding repository. eg: Call for Product's price goes to MyPriceRepository, call for Product's image goes to MyImageRepository. It's a call to WCF service.

Problem now is that the call for a product's image returns a string that is super long - larger than 65KB. Now, what option do I have to store that string? I see from here: https://github.com/ByteInternet/magento-installer/blob/master/lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php , we only have option as far as BLOB? How do I use MEDIUMBLOB?

Comment: Use SQL Create table instead of Modal to create Attribute.

Comment: I think, image is coming as byte code format.
Try to convert into  string.

Comment: The image is coming as string64 format, but it's really long - larger than 65KB. @HoangHieu Can you give more example of this? Right now does Magento support db's field using MEDIUMBLOB?

Comment: You can't use EAV, new a module to control your image data. You can't use default magento, because table varchar of magento is text.